# How to make a cross domain ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have access to a API which is a JSP file and is in JSON format. I am trying to fetch those data from the JSP page to a PHP script and process them and then store in my MySQL sever.

The JSON string is valid in the JSP page I checked in few JSON Formatter and validator online.

This is my code which I am using to get JSON data from the page but, every time my ajax call fails.

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
var url = 'http://xxxxx:8080/StudentAPI/index.jsp';
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(request+textStatus+errorThrown);
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
})
```

Please help me and any suggestion to do it in a better way is always welcomed.

Comment: its a cross domain issue

Comment: @mithunsatheesh:So what alternative do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a cross domain ajax call. So it wont work if you try it just like a normal ajax call.

One way is like to

1. to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*' at the server end to which you are making the ajax request.
2. then make a [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call with the 'crossDomain' attribute 'true' in the settings variable.

Another way would be to use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

depending on on the server you are using you can find how to add cors [in this article](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

#### UPDATE

her is [a w3c article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) which describes how to configure cors in java servlets. See the **In Java servlets** section.

The point is basically that the server which is giving the ajax response should be having
`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` field set to `"*"` in the response headers.

Comment: How can I set Access control allow origin? Where should I set that? can you please tell in details..

Comment: The JSP file in a Tomcat server, I checked for .conf files as mentioned in the first article but I didn't find any conf files.. :(. Do I need to allow in the server where I will place my PHP files?

Comment: no need. it should be in the target server or page of ajax call. which in your case i believe is jsp pages on tomcat. PHP has no part in this issue. you can even make a plain html page hosted on a server and initiate your ajax calls from it.

Comment: did you check the w3c article? i believ you can do something like `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); ` .. sorry if i am wrong as dont have enough exposure to java.

Comment: Struggled for the internet connection for a while :(.. Yes I have written response.addHeader.. Still my problem persists..

Comment: @Dibya : if i were you i would search for how to add a response header in jsp and set the values for `access-control-allow-origin` in the sample code. also refer [this link](http://java-success.blogspot.in/2012/11/cors-and-jquery-with-spring-mvc-restful.html)

Comment: @Dibya : no problems. :)